# Vertical align two lines of text

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am having trouble vertical aligning text in a div.  I have tried suggestions that i have read on other posts.  I'm sure its obvious what I am doing wrong but its not working.

http://jsfiddle.net/o6gqvtoo/

```
<div class="banner">
  <div class="span10"> <!-- bootstrap -->
    <div class="banner-text">
        <div class="pull-left">Here is the first line of text i want to center</div>
        <div class="pull-left">Here is the second line of text i want to center</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.banner{
margin-top:-2;
height: 70px;
background-color: #cf0000;
color: white;
height: 70px;
position: relative;
}

.banner-text{
display: block;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.pull-left {
display: block;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `vertical align` text? - This ? - http://jsfiddle.net/o6gqvtoo/5/

Comment: See also - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div?rq=1

Comment: @Paulie_D if I change the line height that does not work. but yes thats what i would like

Comment: Obviously it does work but perhaps you need to expand on why line height doesn't work...do you have multiple lines?

Comment: @Paulie_D the line height is too big. I want a smaller line height

Comment: Again, why do you need a smaller line height?

Comment: @Paulie_D that is what I want it to look like

Comment: That doesn't **explain** why the smaller line height is required. Perhaps you could provide an image of what this is supposed to look like?

Comment: @Paulie_D I have added an image

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align` is sort of an odd one.

*Generally* you should use it on the elements themselves, not their containers and it's really only for *inline* and *inline-block* elements.

But even then it probably won't vertically center like (I'm guessing) you are wanting. So a little trick is to set your `line-height` to the same as your `height` and voila:

http://jsfiddle.net/06c7eosv/

*Note*: With *display: inline-block* and *width: 50%* you can't have any white space between the elements in your html

Good:

```
<div>...</div><div>...</div>
```

Bad:

```
<div>...</div>
<div>...</div>
```

Comment: this is close. can you put the two lines on separate lines?

Comment: see the photo i have added

Comment: @CamSonaris Oh, if that's all you wanted, just set some padding around the container and let it size itself to the text. Here http://jsfiddle.net/owtw17re/

Answer (score 0):

Based on the supplied image and limited information availableI believe that the best option available is to absolutely position the banner-text wrapper div

```css
.banner {
  margin-top: -2;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #cf0000;
  color: white;
  height: 70px;
  position: relative;
}
.banner-text {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.pull-left {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="span10">
    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <div class="banner-text">
      <div class="pull-left">Here is the first line of text i want to center</div>
      <div class="pull-left">Here is the second line of text i want to center</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That said, other options may be available if the two internal divs can be **combined**.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, `vertical-align` sets the alignment of inline level elements relatively to the line box.

However, in when applied to table cells, it has a different meaning: it sets the alignment of the content inside the cell.

Therefore, you can use CSS tables:

```css
.banner {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.banner > .span10 {
    display: table-row;
}
.banner-text {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
.banner{
  margin-top:-2;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #cf0000;
  color: white;
  height: 70px;
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.banner > .span10 {
  display: table-row;
}
.banner-text{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.pull-left {
  display: block;
  /* float:left; */
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="span10"> <!-- bootstrap -->
    <div class="banner-text">
      <div class="pull-left">Here is the first line of text i want to center</div>
      <div class="pull-left">Here is the second line of text i want to center</div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```